# Passing string between form using property doesnt work

Tags: c#, string, winforms, forms, properties

I know there's a lot of posts here explaining how to pass string between form using Property method, but I just can't make it work. I have Form1 and Form2, in Form1, I open a Bitmap, and I want to pass the path to Form2, so I can access this Bitmap later. If I change the property value inside Form1, it's ok, but when I load Form2 and try to access this information, it is null. I don't know what I am doing wrong, if someone could take a look and find my mistake, I would really apreciate.

Here is my code

Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    String teste;
    public String filePath // this is my property
    {

        get
        {
            return teste;
        }
        set
        {
            teste = value;
        }
    } 

private void OpenMap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // opens the bitmap
    {
     try
        {
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
                pictureBox2.Image = bit;
                pictureBox2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                this.filePath = open.FileName;  // update my property
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { throw new ApplicationException("Falied loading image"); }
    }

private void Next1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // opens form2
    {
        Form2 inicio = new Form2();
        inicio.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

 private void SSc1_1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

}

---

Form  2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Form1 obj = new Form1();
       MessageBox.Show(obj.filePath);
    }
}
```

The problem is the MessageBox is always null..

Thanks in advance
cheers

Comment: At the moment you are creating a new Form1. You want the values from your existing Form. Search this site, the topic pops up at least once a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a property to send the information, form 2 needs a reference to the instance of form 1 to access it.

Right now you are creating a new instance of form 1 from form 2, but as that is not the same instance as the one where you stored the value in the parameter, the parameter of that form doesn't have the value.

You can pass a referene to form 1 into the constructor of form 2:

```
Form2 inicio = new Form2(this);
```

In the constructor you would store that reference for later:'

```
private Form1 _form1;

public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    _form1 = form1;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

When you need the value in the property, you use that reference:

```
MessageBox.Show(_form1.filePath);
```

An alternative to using a property and passing a form reference to the constructor, you could just pass the value itself to the constructor. However, having a reference to the form allows you to add more properties if you need to pass more information between the forms.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a second instance of Form1? You need to reference the existing Form1 not a new one. Either fetch the existing form via Application.OpenForms (or something similar) or store a reference to the form object globally. The Form1 you are accessing has never been shown to the user and thus only had design time values.